# Including "cat" command in unix shell Here Document

Tags: bash, shell, unix, heredoc

I'm trying to create a Here Document which is a shell script that includes the cat command.  Of course, it fails when encountering the 2nd cat. I'm performing a lot of substitutions as well, so can't use the "*DOC*" escape trick.

```
myfile="/tmp/myipaddr"
cat >/usr/bin/setIPaddress <<_DOC_

...     

OUT=`cat $myfile`

...
_DOC_
```

I supposed I could echo into a file, but that seems kludgy and I have a lot of quotes and backticks I'd need to escape?!? Any other thoughts?

Comment: This should work, what is the problem?

Comment: It works. If you are expecting that `OUT` will contain the contents of `cat $myfile`, during (outer) `cat` execution, then you are wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose the file contains

```
hello world
```

As written, the script you generate will contain the line

```
OUT=hello world
```

because the command substitution is performed immediately.

At the very least, you need to quote the line in the here document as

```
OUT="`cat $myfile`"
```

I suspect what you want is to include the literal command substitution in the resulting shell script. To do that, you would want to quote the backticks to prevent them from being evaluated immediately. Better still, use the recommended form of command substitution, `$(...)`, and quote the dollar sign.

```
cat >/usr/bin/setIPaddress <<_DOC_

...     

OUT=\$(cat $myfile)

...
_DOC_
```

`/usr/bin/setIPaddress` will then include the line

```
OUT=$(cat /tmp/myipaddr)
```

Comment: Also more efficient is `OUT=\$(<"$myfile")`.

Comment: Assuming `/usr/bin/setIPaddress` will be executed with `bash`.